# Предел дозволенности или граница дозволенного?

Tags: семантика, выбор-слов

Как правильно:

**Предел дозволенности** или **граница дозволенного**?

Второе, кажется, является устойчивым выражением, поэтому корректнее говорить так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Дозволенное и дозволенность сходны по значению**, сочетаются со словами "степень", "мера", "границы", "уровень" и могут использоваться **в качестве синонимов**, например: Как в самом себе углядеть то, что может привести к роковой ошибке, когда ты переходишь **грань дозволенного**. И кто устанавливает **меру дозволенности**? Чем может завершиться мое увлечение Сашенькой? [Юрий Азаров. Подозреваемый (2002)]

Тем не менее можно отметить **различные оттенки смысла и стиля**. "Дозволенное" подразумевает некое незримое  "авторство", в то время как "дозволенность" ― это общее согласие с нормами поведения на текущий момент.

**Примеры**

1) Когда он вернулся, его встретил иной шум, иная форма протеста, **иное восприятие дозволенности.** [Борис Васильев. Дом, который построил Дед (1990-2000)]

И ― очень тянуло в ту сторону, но, увы, с испуганной оглядкой **на степень дозволенности**. [Андрей Макаревич. Дом (2001)]

2) Главное ― вовремя понять, что ты уже достиг своей стены, **познал предел дозволенного**, предел своего могущества. [Павел Андреев. Афганские рассказы (1998) // «Звезда», 2000]

Аркадий Райкин в жутких масках то бюрократа, то склочника, то бракодела боролся с недостатками внутренними ― и **это был предел дозволенного** смеха. [Андрей Макаревич. «Сам овца». Автобиографическая проза (2000-2001)]

Муки совести Раскольникова не только обнаруживают, что он преступил предел **дозволенного**, но и обличают слабость и ничтожество. [Н. А. Бердяев. Миросозерцание Достоевского (1923)]

Answer (score 2):

Второе выражение действительно устойчиво, более широко распространено и привычно. Что, впрочем, **не** делает первый вариант безграмотным.